# git - Could not resolve hostname

Tags: git

I am in a private network using VPN and using Windows platform. I am trying to clone a git project using

```
git clone ssh://git@domain-name:somestring/str-somestring.git

But I getting ssh: Could not resolve hostname domain-name: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I having `ssh` generated in my local which I added to my local repo as well. Can someone help me out here?

I am sure I all the access for this project.

**Update**

`ping google.com` is working outside VPN, same is not working inside VPN

Comment: Is `domain-name` a valid hostname that resolves? Can you `ping` it?

Comment: @NilsWerner from my command prompt even ping stackoverflow.com is not working, but my domain-name is a valid one. I can successfully able to connect it through web url

Comment: Have you added the `ssh-key` into your hostname settings ?

Comment: @Shravan40 you mean in the host file ?

Comment: @Suganthan : You need to add your local machine ssh key into the `ssh-agent`

Comment: You mean in the web location right? I having that

Comment: Do you have an `~/.ssh/config` file? Just for testing, would you get any error, or the same error message, with `git clone ssh://git@domain-name/somestring/str-somestring.git`

Comment: `config` file is there. While cloning I got the same error as mentioned in question

Comment: i.e. ssh: Could not resolve hostname

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. `git` cannot resolve `domain-name`.

Try, in the same shell you are typing your `git` commands:

```
ping domain-name
nslookup domain-name
```

They won't work either, 99% guaranteed.

If so, the easiest fix is to add that name and its IP address to `/etc/hosts` (as usual, nothing `git` related). When `ping` / `nslookup` work, `git` will as well.

*EDIT to sum up the comments:* The suggestion to modify `/etc/hosts` is primarily for debugging purposes - to directly rule out mysterious DNS issues not related to `git`. It would be much better to fix the actual issue (hard to give real advice about that, as there can be a great many root causes...). Tangentially, a popular problem on MacOS seems to be DNS caching - there are many resources online about this if one searches for "flush dns cache macos".

Comment: Yes, but what happened? What is the output of `ping domain-name`? Does it work or not?

Comment: @Suganthan, if you cannot nslookup a domain, there's a problem with dns service, not git, or the domain is not valid.

You need to get nslookup to work before proceed further.

It's probably because of the domain cannot be recognised in the VPN network.

Can you show the domain here?

Comment: I cannot open the domain here, but when I connecting VPN it is setting some IPV6 address. I doubt that VPN setting a lot

Comment: how to proceed in case that the nslookup succeeded, the git command still says 'could not resolve hostname'

Comment: Make double sure that you have no typos. "Could not resolve hostname" is crystal clear; it can't resolve a hostname via DNS.

Comment: So @AnoE I have an example in front of me where (on linux) I can look up the host name, and ping it but git says it couldn't resolve the host name. And while I believe Git can't for some reason, it shows that your comments may not always be true.

Comment: A really weird situation with globalprotect client on mac is somehow git ignore the domain available on the corp VPN, so nslookup work but git fail. The /etc/hosts trick works though

Comment: Hello, it's me, the 1%: `nslookup` works, but `ping` didn't (`ping: cannot resolve <host>: Unknown host`), on Mac. Adding the host to `/etc/hosts` both got `ping` working and unblocked the `git push` - and, strangely, both still work even _after_ removing the host from `/etc/hosts` (I guess there's some caching of looked-up results going on?) - but, clearly, manually adding hosts one-by-one to `/etc/hosts` isn't a satisfactory solution. Any tips on how I can understand this disparity better and resolve it properly?

Comment: @scubbo, google "macos dns caching", you'll get plenty of hits of how to flush that cache (and about its existence...).